# Why do some websites have just http:// in URL address without www.?

Tags: internet

This is not a programming question, but something I was curious for a long time. I am a web developer myself, but do not know the answer to this question. I notice some websites have just http:// in their address, with no www. (eg. http-colon-//delicious) and other websites have www. in their address (eg. http-colon-//www-dot-yahoo-dot-com)

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: You can have opinion from people who made these sites at this link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/dropping-the-www-prefix/

Comment: The basic idea is that "www." is part of a computer's name.  (Whether that is actually true may be blurred by the fact that some websites have multiple computers acting as web servers.  Let's ignore the complications from that design.)  A single IP address (in simple terms, you can often think of that as a single computer) can have multiple names, such as both www.example.com and example.com.  Whether www.example.com is a valid name, or whether it even exists, depends on the decision made by whoever controls (and bothered to set up) the (example.com) domain name.

Answer (score 1):

The `www` is not required, so some sites dispense with it.

Comment: I hate having to type `www`. And nothing gets more annoying than sites that do not properly DNS themselves, and force you to type `www`.

Comment: you should be aware that there are some kind of annoying cookie side effects when your base domain does not begin with `www` but that is more of a programmer issue than a user one.

Answer (score 1):

The *www* is a convention from when the web was small and much less important than it is today. It is entirely optional (although can be useful for a domain to organize its cookies)

Answer (score 1):

www is the conventional prefix, but it is not mandatory. Particularly if you already have a subdomain, skipping the extra www prefix just leaves a shorter address:

foo.acme.com rather than www.foo.acme.com reads better.

Answer (score 1):

The `www` part of the URL is a sub domain.  It is completely at the discretion of the owner of the domain whether or not `www` or any other sub domain is used.

There are many sites out there that prefer not to use `www` and even some that think it should be deprecated.  Check out http://no-www.org, who have "validated" thousands of sites that don't use the `www` part of the domain.